# Sharepoint 2007 and <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: html, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2007, doctype, standards-compliance

Greetings...

I'm trying to get my Sharepoint 2007 site to render in Standards mode when browsing in IE.
Since "!DOCTYPE html" makes every browser that I might be worrying about do just that, I decided to use it.

I've read here and there that Standards mode could cause unwanted behavior to some OOTB functionality and style (fly-outs, calendar items, etc...), but can't find a full list containing error reference and ways to correct it.

So, I'm looking for any kind of info and guidance on the matter...
Just trying to avoid endless clicking through my app and hopping that some one altruistic by nature has gone through testing hell already and is willing to share.

Thanks...

Comment: Why are you putting your face against this particular cheese grater? I mean, what's the business rational? Apart from a religious style crusade for standards why wouldn't you take the easy path and just let it be? ;)

Comment: Please don't try to make Sharepoint 2007 standard compliant. It's a never ending story - just take it like it is. Sharepoint 2010 is a lot better - but still doesn't validate, it's just not Microsoft's thing - just look at IE.

Comment: Oh no, it's not a validation and standards thing. Standards are nice and important and I eagerly await the day that all browsers will comply. But real life sharepoint branding projects, at least in my experience, tend to be significantly simpler if I ignore them. Sad but true.
@Ryan - had to google "cheese greater" and I have to agree: that's exactly what it feels like to custom brand preexisting sharepoint site.
@moontear - ok, I won't try, since you asked so nicely :)

Answer (score 2):

Heather Solomon lists some of the problems that will occur when using quirks mode and offers some fixes - not sure if its complete though.

[The DOCTYPE tag and SharePoint Master Pages](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2007/02/21/6213.aspx)

[DOCTYPES and SharePoint](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2008/01/25/DOCTYPES-and-SharePoint.aspx)

Comment: thanks man, Heather was probably the first reference source that I started using when i first met SP a year ago and I still check to see what she had to say. I just wanted to check if there is more complete list...

Comment: Thanks for sharing those links. I can only get my publishing pages to behave right if I also use x-ua-compatible for IE 7. Otherwise the SharePoint toolbar/menu at the top of publishing pages and editing of publishing pages doesn't work correctly in IE 8 & 9. It gets all kinds of script errors.

Answer (score 1):

You might what to take a look at http://gsptv.codeplex.com/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The only viable option is to install the latest service packs and cumulative updates. SharePoint 2007 uses too many "quirky" features to fix by hand

Comment: good advice, but it would take 2 weeks to get somebody to authorize an update + 2 more for someone to do it. It's 4 company joint project that I'm working on, don't ask...