# How can I tell an image that is bigger than the window to scale to fit in a div in sharepoint IE quirks mode?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, doctype, quirks-mode

So im in sharepoint building a jquery slider inside of a webpart. The images I am working with are 1920x300 and my slider scales them to fit into a liquid design. Sharepoint template is also liquid / fluid. In IE, Sharepoint renders in quirks mode because for some reason they do not use a doctype. When the document loads I see the initial image scale down but once the script fires they go to full size and push my layout off the page. Can someone explain what is happening here?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){

    var quan = $(document).width();
    $('html').css({maxWidth: quan+'px',overflow: 'hidden'});

    $.fn.extend({
        mainSlider: function(options) {

            //default values for plugin options
            var defaults = {
                interval: 5000,
                duration: 500,
                lineheight: 1,
                height: 'auto', //reserved
                hoverpause: true,
                pager: true,
                nav: true, //reserved
                keynav: true
            }
            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var o = options;
                var obj = $(this);

                //store the slide and pager li
                var slides = $('.slides li', obj);
                var pager = $('.pager li', obj);
                var cap = $('.caption');

                //set initial current and next slide index values
                var current = 0;
                var next = current+1;

                //get height and width of initial slide image and calculate size ratio
                var imgHeight = slides.eq(current).find('img').height();
                var imgWidth = slides.eq(current).find('img').width();
                var imgRatio = imgWidth/imgHeight;

                //define vars for setsize function
                var sliderWidth = 0;
                var cropHeight = 0;

                //hide all slides, fade in the first, add active class to first slide
                slides.hide().eq(current).fadeIn(o.duration).addClass('active');


                //build pager if it doesn't already exist and if enabled
                if(pager.length) {
                    pager.eq(current).addClass('active');
                } else if(o.pager){
                    obj.append('<ul class="pager"></ul>');
                    slides.each(function(index) {
                        $('.pager', obj).append('<li><a href="#"><span>'+index+'</span></a></li>')
                    });
                    pager = $('.pager li', obj);
                    pager.eq(current).addClass('active');
                }

                //rotate to selected slide on pager click
                if(pager){
                    $('a', pager).click(function() {
                        //stop the timer
                        clearTimeout(obj.play);
                        //set the slide index based on pager index
                        next = $(this).parent().index();
                        //rotate the slides
                        rotate();
                        return false;
                    });
                }

                //primary function to change slides
                var rotate = function(){
                    //fade out current slide and remove active class,
                    //fade in next slide and add active class
                    var name = slides.eq(next).find('a').attr('title');
                    var dlink = slides.eq(next).find('a').attr('href');
                    var tex = slides.eq(next).find('img').attr('alt');
                    cap.slideToggle('slow',function(){
                        $(this).empty().append('<a href='+dlink+' title='+name+'>'+tex+name+'</a>')
                    });
                    slides.eq(current).fadeOut(o.duration).removeClass('active')
                        .end().eq(next).fadeIn(o.duration).addClass('active').queue(function(){
                            //add rotateTimer function to end of animation queue
                            //this prevents animation buildup caused by requestAnimationFrame
                            //rotateTimer starts a timer for the next rotate
                            rotateTimer();
                            $(this).dequeue();
                            cap.slideToggle();
                    });

                    //Update the Caption


                    //update pager to reflect slide change
                    if(pager){
                        pager.eq(current).removeClass('active')
                            .end().eq(next).addClass('active');
                    }

                    //update current and next vars to reflect slide change
                    //set next as first slide if current is the last
                    current = next;
                    next = current >= slides.length-1 ? 0 : current+1;
                };
                //create a timer to control slide rotation interval
                var rotateTimer = function(){
                    obj.play = setTimeout(function(){
                        //trigger slide rotate function at end of timer
                        rotate();
                    }, o.interval);
                };
                //start the timer for the first time
                rotateTimer();

                //pause the slider on hover
                //disabled by default due to bug
                if(o.hoverpause){
                    slides.hover(function(){
                        //stop the timer in mousein
                        clearTimeout(obj.play);
                    }, function(){
                        //start the timer on mouseout
                        rotateTimer();
                    });
                }

                //calculate and set height based on image width/height ratio and specified line height
                var setsize = function(){
                    sliderWidth = $('.slides', obj).width();
                    cropHeight = Math.floor(((sliderWidth/imgRatio)/o.lineheight))*o.lineheight;

                    $('.slides', obj).css({height: cropHeight});
                };
                setsize();

                //bind setsize function to window resize event
                $(window).resize(function(){
                    setsize();
                });



                //Add keyboard navigation

                if(o.keynav){
                    $(document).keyup(function(e){

                        switch (e.which) {

                            case 39: case 32: //right arrow & space

                                clearTimeout(obj.play);

                                rotate();

                                break;


                            case 37: // left arrow
                                clearTimeout(obj.play);
                                next = current - 1;
                                rotate();

                                break;
                        }

                    });
                }


            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var ftex = $('.slides li').first().find('img').attr('alt');
    var flink = $('.slides li').first().find('img').attr('alt');
    $('.caption').empty().append('<a href='+flink+' title='+ftex+'>'+ftex+'</p>');  
    $('.mainSlider').mainSlider({
        interval: 5000,
        duration: 500,
        lineheight: 1,
        hoverpause: false,
        pager: true,
        keynav: true
    });
//End Window Load
});
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <style>     .mainSlider { width:100%; overflow:hidden; }
<![endif]-->
<style>
        .mainSlider { margin: 0 auto; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
        .mainSlider ul{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
            .mainSlider .slides {
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .mainSlider .slides li {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .mainSlider .slides li img {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: none;
            }
            .mainSlider .slides li img:hover {
                opacity: .95;
                filter:alpha(opacity=95); /* For IE8 and earlier */
            }
            .mainSlider .slides li.active { display: block; position: relative; }
            .mainSlider .crop li img { width: auto; }

            .mainSlider .pager {
                position:relative;
                float:right;
                margin: -40px 10px 0px 0px;
                height: 40px;
                max-width: 300px;
                text-align: right;
                z-index: 10000;
            }
            .mainSlider .pager li { float: left;}
            .mainSlider .pager li a,
            .mainSlider .pager li a span {
                display: block;
                height: 16px;
                width: 16px;
            }
            .mainSlider .pager li a {
                padding: 8px 8px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
               -moz-border-radius: 6px;
                border-radius: 6px;
            }
            .mainSlider .pager li a span {
                overflow: hidden;
                background: #dfdfdf;
                text-indent: 9999px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
               -moz-border-radius: 2px;
                border-radius: 2px;
            }
            .mainSlider .pager li.active a span { background: #404040; }
            .caption {
                position:absolute;
                display:table-cell;
                vertical-align:middle;
                height: 50px;
                width: 100%;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                padding: 10px;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
                box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
                background-image: url(http://mysite.nrc.gov/personal/ewg1/Personal%20Documents/capBG.png);
                background-repeat:repeat-x;
                z-index: 9999;
            }
            .caption a{
                color: #000;
                text-align:left;
                font-size:24px;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
            .caption a:hover{
                color: #003366;
                text-decoration: none;
            }


</style>
  <div id="sliderContent">

<!-- mainSlider -->

    <div class="mainSlider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <div class="caption"><p></p></div>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title=""><img alt="What do I do at Region II?" src="http://mysite.nrc.gov/personal/ewg1/Personal%20Documents/tronCar.jpg" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title=""><img alt="Graphic Design..." src="http://mysite.nrc.gov/personal/ewg1/Personal%20Documents/bueTiger.jpg" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title=""><img alt="Web Design..." src="http://mysite.nrc.gov/personal/ewg1/Personal%20Documents/squares.jpg" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title=""><img alt="Audio..." src="http://mysite.nrc.gov/personal/ewg1/Personal%20Documents/audioProduction.jpg" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title=""><img alt="Audio..." src="http://mysite.nrc.gov/personal/ewg1/Personal%20Documents/videoProduction.jpg" /></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

<!-- mainSlider -->

  </div>
```

Comment: a bit of code or fiddle to demonstrate the error would be useful

Comment: Don't try to make stuff work in quirks mode, unless you like pulling out your hair. Check out the answers from [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169609/sharepoint-2007-and-doctype-html)

Comment: Sharepoint does not use a doctype which auto throws IE into Quirks I cant even force it out

Comment: There you go Pete, I cant provide a fiddle unless you know of a sharepoint fiddle?!?

Answer (score 0):

The image scales down initially due to the reflow caused by modifying the DOM with jQuery. Use the following to scale with CSS:

- [CSS Fit-and-Shrink Technique](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/fast.html)

**References**

- [-ms-interpolation-mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530822)